# My MPI jacobi iteration program gives wrong result

Tags: c, mpi, linear-algebra

I got the above mentioned error on running the following program in C.

This program Firstly generates 3x3 array and executes Jacobi iteration. It uses MPI library. I don't know what parts of code are wrong.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h> // l2-norm //
#include <time.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int numprocs, myid;
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);

double a[3][3];
double b[3];
double x[3]={0};
double xa[3]={0};
double xnew[3]={0};
double y[3]={0};
float sigancha;
time_t startTime=0, endTime=0;
int n=3;
int i, j =0;
int k=0;
int o;
int hoessu=300;
int minhoessu=300;
double sum=1;
int numsent =0;
int ans;
int row;
MPI_Status status;
int sender;
int po;
double *buffer;
/* synchronization */
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        b[i]=i*100;
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
                a[i][j]=((i+j)%10);
                if (i==j) {a[i][j]+=5000;}
        }
        x[i]=b[i]/a[i][i];
}
/* run if sum is greater than 0.0002 */

for (k=0; k<hoessu&&sum>0.0002||k<minhoessu; k++) {

numsent = 0;
for (o=myid+1; o<n+1; o+=numprocs) {
    i=o-1;
    xa[i]=b[i]+a[i][i]*x[i];
    for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
    xa[i]-=a[i][j]*x[j];
    }
xnew[i]=xa[i]/a[i][i];
/*send xnew[i] to master*/
MPI_Send(&xnew[i],1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,i,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

if (myid == 0){
/*get xnew[i]*/
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
MPI_Recv(&ans, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
sender = status.MPI_SOURCE;
row = status.MPI_TAG;
xnew[row] = ans;
}

/*calculates sum at master*/

for (j=0; j<n; j++){
    sum=0.0;
    sum+=(xnew[j]-x[j])*(xnew[j]-x[j]);
    x[j]=xnew[j];
}
sum=pow(sum,0.5);
MPI_Bcast(&x[0], n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
}

if (myid == 0){
        endTime=clock();
        sigancha=(float)(endTime-startTime)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        printf("finished\n");
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
                printf("x[%d]=%fl\n",j+1,xnew[j]);
        }

        printf("iteration; %d times itereation are done. \n l2-norm, error is %fl .\n %f seceonds are used. \n",k,sum,sigancha);
}
        MPI_Finalize();

}
```

Uses mpicc for compile.

```
 mpicc mpijacobi2.c -o taskingyeje  
 ./taskingyeje
```

Result.

```
finished
x[1]=-1736884775.000000l
x[2]=-370936800.000000l
x[3]=2118301216.000000l
iteration; 300 times itereation are done. 
 l2-norm, error is 34332272.000000l .
 0.020000 seceonds are used.
```

however, this result is not intended result. If this program worked perfectly, It should give same result of serial jacobi iteration.
It would be

```
x[1]=-0.000020l
x[2]=-0.019968l
x[3]=0.399956l
```

I don't know why this program generate wrong result.

Comment: The message is self explanatory ! your app `MPI_Send()` to rank `i+1`, and it is likely this rank is greater or equal than `num_procs`, especially since you hardcoded `n-3` and ran a single MPI task.

Comment: oh, I should change i+1 to 0. But it is nor enough.

Comment: erroneous result was observed

Comment: please indent your code properly, and edit the question with a description of the observed vs expected result. comments are hard to read, but from what I can tell, `error is 0.000000` looks pretty good.

Comment: I finished and solved the problem.

Comment: Please consider the following for any new question. Always include a properly formatted [mcve]. Do not change your question once you solve one part of it and run into a totally different error. If you find the solution yourself, post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: If you have solved the problem, please post an answer, and accept it once the system allows you to. Don't leave questions unanswered - especially when you've solved one.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h> // l2-norm //
#include <time.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int numprocs, myid;
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);

double a[700][700];
double b[700];
double x[700]={0};
double xa[700]={0};
double xnew[700]={0};
double y[700]={0};
float sigancha;
time_t startTime=0, endTime=0;
int n=700;
int i, j =0;
int k=0;
int o;
int hoessu=300;
int minhoessu=300;
double sum=1;
int numsent =0;
int ans;
int row;
MPI_Status status;
int sender;
int po;
double *buffer;
/* synchronization */
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        b[i]=i*100;
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
                a[i][j]=((i+j)%10);
                if (i==j) {a[i][j]+=10000;}
        }
        x[i]=b[i]/a[i][i];
}
/* run if sum is greater than 0.0002 */

for (k=0; k<hoessu&&sum>0.0002||k<minhoessu; k++) {

numsent = 0;
for (o=myid+1; o<n+1; o+=numprocs) {
    i=o-1;
    xa[i]=b[i]+a[i][i]*x[i];
    for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
    xa[i]-=a[i][j]*x[j];
    }
xnew[i]=xa[i]/a[i][i];
/*send xnew[i] to master*/
ans=xnew[i];
MPI_Allgather(&xnew[i],1,MPI_DOUBLE,&xnew[i],1,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

if (myid == 0){

/*calculates sum at master*/

for (j=0; j<n; j++){
    sum=0.0;
    sum+=(xnew[j]-x[j])*(xnew[j]-x[j]);
    x[j]=xnew[j];
}
sum=pow(sum,0.5);
MPI_Bcast(&x[0], n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
}

if (myid == 0){
        endTime=clock();
        sigancha=(float)(endTime-startTime)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        printf("finished\n");
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
                printf("x[%d]=%fl\n",j+1,xnew[j]);
        }

        printf("iteration; %d times itereation are done. \n l2-norm, error is %fl .\n %f seceonds are used. \n",k,sum,sigancha);
}
        MPI_Finalize();

}
```